# iOS RxSwift does connectable observable from .replay() pass completion events to subscribers?

Tags: observable, swift4, ios11, rx-swift

I’m trying to get some more clarity around connectable Observables.

**Does connectable observable pass `onComplete` events to subscribers at the end of replay, if source has terminated?**

I have seen answer suggesting that it should, but it does not seem to do so in RxSwift. Is this my bug, or is this the correct behavior in swift?

```
let source = Observable.just(“test”).replay()
let disposable = source.subscribe(onNext:{}, onComplete:{print(“would this print?”})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `replay` operator returns a connectable Observable, which means it doesn't produce anything until it's been `connect`ed.

Your print statement will output if you call connect()

```
    let source = Observable.just("test").replay(1)
    source.subscribe(onNext: {_ in }, onCompleted: { print("would this print?") })
        .disposed(by: bag)
    source.connect()
        .disposed(by: bag)
```